# Positive and negative parts of an unbounded self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

This question is about the proof of lemma 14 in [1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1446788700004560), which deals with the decomposition of an unbounded self-adjoint operator $A$ in positive and negative parts: $A = A^+ - A^-$. I have trouble understanding the proof given at the bottom of page 27 that $A^- \geq 0$.

Indeed, the author writes that $(A^+ + A^-)Ex = |A|Ex$, where $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ and $E$ is the orthogonal projector onto $\mathcal{N}(A^+)$. This seems to assume that $Ex \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ but I don't see where this would come from. Any idea?

[Bernau, S. (1968). The square root of a positive self-adjoint operator. Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society, 8(01), p.17.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1446788700004560)

EDIT: ~~In fact, I wonder whether one could not start to prove that $|A| - A \geq 0$. Since $A^-$ is the closure of this operator, the result would follow, right?~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So stupid of me! I had simply forgotten that $A = A^+ - A^-$ by point i), hence in particular $\mathcal{D}(A^+) \cap \mathcal{D}(A^-) = \mathcal{D}(A)$.